Cannot access LoadBalancer service of Django deployment on EKS cluster
I have a containerized Django application that was successfully deployed (imperatively) to an EKS cluster. I've used the following commands:
kubectl create deployment announcements --port=127 --image=public.ecr.aws/x7a1r0o7/announcements-dev --port=127
[gunicorn exposes the container on port 127. If I exec into the pod, it works, and a curl for localhost:127 gives me the html of the page]
Then I create the service using
kubectl expose deployment/announcements --type=LoadBalancer --port-127
I tried different ports like 80 and 8000 when exposing the deployment. I've also verified that the Pod has the files and the internal curl shows the application is running.
For some reason, when I kubectl get svc and use the external IP (an AWS ELB web address) I am unable to see the application. Nothing is served. Any insight would be appreciated.
